# How to deploy spring batch application with helm chart

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-batch, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy my spring-batch application in k8s using helm.

My application inside resource folder has many application.yaml files that look like at the following:

```
job:
  name: my-job
  isActive: true
  ..... other stuff
```

Now I have created a chart template with the following skeleton:

```
 batch
   templates
      configmap.yaml
      job.yaml
      pvc.yaml
      secret.yaml
      serviceaccount.yaml
   Chart.yaml
   values.yaml
 values
   test
     values.yaml
```

My configmap.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-job.fullname" . }}-config
  labels: {{ include "helm-job.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  application.yaml: {{ toYaml .Values.application | indent 2 | trim }}
```

My values.yaml:

```
application: |-
  job:
    name: test
```

I'm installing this chart using the command:

> helm upgrade --install batch --namespace test --values
> ./values/test/values.yaml /values.yaml ./batch

After the install command when i try to see the env variable of my pod using:

> kubectl exec -it mypod -n
> test -- env

I'm getting this:

[image]

job.name is not transalte like env variable, same suggestion about this?
Where I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

Adding

```
spec:
  containers:
  env: |+
  {{ .Files.Get "values/application.yaml" | indent 4 }}
```

in my job.yaml I'm getting this error:

Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Job.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.env: got "string", expected "array"

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting is consistent with your Helm definition.

If you want to use environment variables inside your pod, you should add the `env` definition into the file where you declare the pod; in your case it should be the `job.yaml` file. So, add these lines:

```
spec:
  containers:
  env:
    - name: {{ .Values.application.name }}
      value: {{ .Values.application.value }}
```

In the `values.yaml` file declare:

```
application:
  name: JOB_NAME
  value: test
```

Alternativelly, you can use an external file `application.yaml` with the list of names and values:

```
- name1: JOB1
  value: value1
- name: JOB2
  value: value2
```

and load them into the `job.yaml` file as:

```
spec:
  containers:
  env: |+
{{ .Files.Get "values/application.yaml" | indent 4 }}
```

Comment: My target is to translate my application.yaml in env variables and then i would get JOB_NAME = test inside my pod so is recognized from spring application

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. I updated my answer with your expected result.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggests, but my problem is that i have  about 50 row in my application.yaml and i would want to transale them directly using configmap loaded im my pod. In your opinion is this possible?

Comment: I edited my answer, adding the possiiblity to load values from aan external file. You can do it, but in any case you have to specify the env variables in the job.yaml, not in configmap

Comment: I updated my question, what do you think about this?